# Terraform resource inheritance

Tags: terraform

Is there a way to declare an abstract resource to inherit from?

Example:

```
resource "digitalocean_droplet" "worker_abstract" {
  abstract = true // ???

  name = "swarm-worker-${count.index}"
  tags = [
    "${digitalocean_tag.swarm_worker.id}"
  ]

  // other config stuff

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    //...
  }
}
```

And then use declared resource with overridden variables:

```
resource "worker_abstract" "worker_foo" {
  count = 2
  name = "swarm-worker-foo-${count.index}"
  tags = [
    "${digitalocean_tag.swarm_worker.id}",
    "${digitalocean_tag.foo.id}"
  ]
}

resource "worker_abstract" "worker_bar" {
  count = 5
  name = "swarm-worker-bar-${count.index}"
  tags = [
    "${digitalocean_tag.swarm_worker.id}"
    "${digitalocean_tag.bar.id}"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Currently it looks like this is not possible, but there is an open feature request here: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/353

Answer (score 8):

This might be a little more "verbose" of a solution than what you're proposing, but this sounds like a perfect use-case for [modules in 0.12](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/index.html).

You could create a module, say in the file `worker/main.tf`

```
variable "instances" {
  type = number
}

variable "name" {
  type = string
}

variable "tags" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = []
}

resource "digitalocean_droplet" "worker" {
  count = var.instances

  name = "swarm-worker-${var.name}-${count.index}"
  tags = var.tags

  // other config stuff

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    //...
  }
}
```

then you could consume your module almost exactly like your example (let's say from the directory above `worker`)

```
module "worker_foo" {
  source = "./worker"

  instances = 2
  name = "foo"
  tags = [
    "${digitalocean_tag.swarm_worker.id}",
    "${digitalocean_tag.foo.id}"
  ]
}

module "worker_bar" {
  source = "./worker"

  instances = 5
  name = "bar"
  tags = [
    "${digitalocean_tag.swarm_worker.id}"
    "${digitalocean_tag.bar.id}"
  ]
}
```